# MUI: Overriding easing/timing function in Slide Transition component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I add easings to the Material-UI `Slide` component? I'm not seeing the props that would allow this. But I read something somewhere about spreading props?

```
<Slide
  in={variable}
  timeout={500}
  direction="right"
  mountOnEnter={true}
  unmountOnExit={true}
>
    <Child />
</Slide>
```

Comment: As the documentation says [Slide](https://material-ui.com/api/slide/) uses [Transition](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-props) and as you can see on their website its timing function can be modified by CSS - et.: `transition: opacity ${duration}ms ease-in-out,`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MUI v5, you can change the default timing functions of the `Slide` component by overriding the `easing` props:

```js
<Slide
  direction="up"
  in={checked}
  easing={{
    enter: "cubic-bezier(0, 1.5, .8, 1)",
    exit: "linear"
  }}
>
  {icon}
</Slide>
```

[image: Edit 67128388/material-ui-slide-transition-component-with-easing]

In MUI v4, you need to override the timing function defined in [`theme.transitions.easing.easeOut`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1617f4ee72920d40d0b0f9dac34f90b82dadf4bf/packages/material-ui/src/Slide/Slide.js#L137) for enter transition and [`theme.transitions.easing.sharp`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1617f4ee72920d40d0b0f9dac34f90b82dadf4bf/packages/material-ui/src/Slide/Slide.js#L165) for exit transition.

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  transitions: {
    easing: {
      easeOut: "cubic-bezier(0, 1.5, .8, 1)",
      sharp: "linear"
    }
  }
});
```

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Slide direction="up" in={checked}>
    {icon}
  </Slide>
</ThemeProvider>
```

[image: Edit 67128388/material-ui-slide-transition-component-with-easing-v4]

Comment: How would you use a different transition from the ones already provided in the default theme? I assume you would have to bring in the theme object somehow, but the easing attribute doesn't seem to support the arrow function scheme 
`easing={(theme)=>
  {
    easeOut: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
    sharp: theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut
  }
}`